# CA workload automation AE (autosys) dependent jobs can't start

Tags: ca, autosys

I encountered a weird problem in using CA workload automation AE (autosys). The dependent jobs couldn't start even when starting conditions were satisfied. The status of the dependent jobs are `Activated`, because all the jobs (starting condition jobs and dependent jobs) are in a same box, as the snapshot shows:

[image: CA job snapshot]

Did somebody have the same problem? Thanks for your help and share!

Comment: Can u share JIL for anyone of the box in which you are facing it ?

Comment: Also, what's the status of the job represented with left arrow sign along with red strike ?

Comment: " the job represented with left arrow sign along with red strike" means `on no execution`

Comment: JIL of the box:
`insert_job: KEY_JOB_RERUN_SNAIL   job_type: BOX 
owner: ejmcommander
permission: 
date_conditions: 0
run_window: "1:00-22:00"
condition: s(sh_m1001_check_recal_salestockkd_snail)
description: "manual run BI key job, sale, stock, customer transaction amount etc."
alarm_if_fail: 1
group: KEY_JOB_RERUN`

Comment: Did anyone have any idea?